# Can the integral of a "generic" bounded measurable function be determined by its values on the rationals?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

[This question is an extension of my question [Does a positive-measure subset of the unit interval almost surely intersect a random translation of some countable subgroup of $\mathbb{R}$?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/210316/does-a-positive-measure-subset-of-the-unit-interval-almost-surely-intersect-a-ra). I'm asking it to help me solve my question [Do the Birkhoff averages of a measurable stationary homogeneous Markov process in continuous time "converge to the right limit"?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/199540/do-the-birkhoff-averages-of-a-measurable-stationary-homogeneous-markov-process-i). ]

> > Does there exist a measurable function $F\colon [0,1]^{\mathbb{Q}\cap [0,1]} \to [0,1]$ with the property that for every measurable $f\colon [0,\infty) \to [0,1]$, for Lebesgue-almost all $\tau \geq 0$ we have
> >     $$ \int_\tau^{\tau+1} f(t) \, dt \ = \ F\left( \, (f(\tau+q))_{q \in \mathbb{Q}\cap [0,1]} \, \right) \ ? $$

Given all the results to the effect that "measurable objects are approximately topological objects", it seems highly intuitive that the answer should be *yes*. In fact, it even seems intuitive to me that the function
$$ F\left( \, (r_q)_{q \in \mathbb{Q}\cap [0,1]} \, \right) \ := \ \limsup_{n \to \infty} \, \frac{1}{2^n} \sum_{k=0}^{2^n-1} r_{\!\frac{k}{2^n}} $$
should  work, but I have not managed to prove it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes your $F$ works. This is a result of B. Jessen, "On the Approximation of Lebesgue Integrals by Riemann Sums", Annals of Mathematics Second Series, Vol. 35, No. 2 (Apr., 1934), pp. 248-251.

I found this by googling "Strong Sweeping Out" and "Riemann sums". If you do the Riemann sum along multiples of $1/n$, however, things don't work at all as you take the limit as $n\to\infty$. You might look at the notes of Wierdl and Rosenblatt in the Cambridge University Press book for more info.

EDIT: So here are some more details of why your $F$ works. 
Define 
$$
\Lambda(f)(x)=\limsup_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{2^n}\sum_{i=0}^{2^n-1}f(x+i/2^n).
$$
By Jessen's theorem, if $f$ is 1-periodic, then $\Lambda(f)(x)=\int_0^1 f$ for Lebesgue-a.e. $x$.

For $q\in\mathbb Q$, define a map $\Pi_q$ sending a measurable function $f$ to the measurable 1-periodic function agreeing with $f$ on $[q,q+1)$ and let $\Lambda_q=\Lambda\circ\Pi_q$. By Jessen's theorem, $\Lambda_q(f)(x)=\int_q^{q+1}f$ for Lebesgue a.e. $x$. 
Let $A_q=\{x\colon \Lambda_q(f)(x)=\int_q^{q+1}f\}$. 
If $f$ is bounded, it's straightforward to see that $\Lambda_q(f)(x)\to\Lambda(f)(x)$ as $q\to x$ and also that $\int_q^{q+1}f\to\int_x^{x+1}f$ for all $x$.

Now if $x\in\bigcap_q A_q$ (a set of full Lebesgue measure), we have $\Lambda(f)(x)=\lim_{q\to x}\Lambda_q(f)(x)
=\lim_{q\to x}\int_q^{q+1}f=\int_x^{x+1}f$.

By the way, I believe that Jessen's theorem follows quickly from the backwards martingale convergence theorem if you take the $\sigma$-algebras to be $\mathcal F_n=\{B\in\mathcal B\colon B+2^{-n}=B\pmod 1\}$.

Comment: Thank you for drawing my attention to this. The paper that you cited seems to only consider the case that $f$ is 1-periodic (i.e. has a periodicity matching the width of the interval being integrated over). Is there any easy way to extend to the more general case? Or did you find a reference that gives the more general case?

Comment: My guess is that you could obtain the general case from this by fiddling around.

Comment: @JulianNewman: Did you manage to obtain the result you wanted from the Jessen result? My guess is that you could create a finite set of periodic functions from your original $f$ and use them to show that for each $\epsilon$, you're within $\epsilon$ of the right thing on a set of full measure and then finish up by taking a countable intersection.

Comment: I have to admit, I am really struggling to see how I can derive the general case as a *corollary* of the case where the periodicity coincides with (or is an integral factor of) the width of the range of integration. (Nonetheless, I might possibly be able to extend Jessen's method of proof to the more general situation; I have not gone through the paper yet.)

Comment: Thank you very much for this! (I had a vague feeling that continuity of $\Lambda_r(f)(x)$ in $r$ might be relevant, but couldn't see how to make a proof out of that.) In your argument for Jessen's theorem: taking $\mathbb{P}$ to be the Lebesgue measure on $[0,1]$, I can see that $\mathbb{E}[f|\mathcal{F}_n](x)$ is the $n$-th step in the Riemann-sum approximation of $\int_x^{x+1} f$; however, I cannot see why $\mathbb{E}[f|\mathcal{F}_\infty]$ is almost everywhere equal to the integral of $f$ (over a period).

Comment: Oh, I think I can see it now: If we take any $B \in \mathcal{F}_\infty$ with $\mathbb{P}(B)>0$, then due to the Lebesgue density theorem (combined with the fact that $B \in \mathcal{F}_n$ for very large $n$) we can show that $\mathbb{P}(B)>1-\varepsilon$ for every $\varepsilon>0$, and therefore $\mathbb{P}(B)=1$.